# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

Hi All I'm facing an error which i dont know the solution

```
for (var i = 0; i < oData.results.length; i++) {
                debugger;
                /* eslint no-console: 0*/
                console.log(oData.resutls[i].ColName);
                //  oTable.bindAggregation(function(index, context) {
                //      return new sap.m.Column({
                //          header: new sap.m.Label({
                //              text: oData.results[i].ColName
                //              debugger;
                //          }),
                //      });
                //  });
            }
```

the error is Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined 
any solustions please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote oData.resutls instead of oData.results in the console.log statement.